# rainbow color heatmap wanted?

Tags: c#

I have the following function to create heat map colors from red to green. It works well.
But now I need a rainbow color heatmap from red via yellow and green to blue.
How could this be achieved by modifiying the following code?

```
 public Color HeatMapColor(double value, double min, double max)
        {

            if (value < min)
            {
                return Color.LightGray;

            }
            else if (value > max)
            {
                return Color.Black;

            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    double val = (value - min) / (max - min);


                    int r = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(255 * val));
                    int g = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(255 * (1 - val)));
                    int b = 0;

                    if (r > 255 || r < 0)
                        r = 255;
                    if (g > 255 || g < 0) g = 255;
                    else if (b > 255 || b < 0) b = 255;

                    return Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
                } 
                catch (OverflowException)
                {


                    return Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modified version of Jeroen's work. Acknowledgement to him. If you have to get a specific color for a specific value within the rainbow color gradient, use the following code:

```
private Color[] colorsRainbow = new[] { Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue };
```

and continue with:

```
private Color GetRainbowColor(double value, Color[] colors)
        {
            var colorRange = colors.Length - 1;
             var newValue = value * colorRange;
              var startIndex = (int)newValue;
               var residualValue = newValue - startIndex;
            var endIndex = startIndex + 1;

            if (startIndex > 3)
                startIndex = 3;
            if (startIndex < 0)
                startIndex = 0;

            if (endIndex > 3)
                endIndex = 3;
            if (endIndex < 0)
                endIndex = 0;


            return LerpColor(residualValue, colors[startIndex], colors[endIndex]);
        }

        public Color LerpColor(double value, Color startColor, Color endColor)
        {
            
                if (value < 0) {
                    value = 0;
                } else if (value >= 1)
                    value = 0.99999;

                int r = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(endColor.R * value)) + System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(startColor.R * (1 - value)));
                int g = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(endColor.G * value)) + System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(startColor.G * (1 - value)));
                int b = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(endColor.B * value)) + System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(startColor.B * (1 - value)));
             
                
                return Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
           
            
        }
```

call the function like this:

```
double val = (data - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue);
fill = GetRainbowColor(val, colorsRainbow);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [lerping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) from 0.0 to 1.0 between two colors, you need to scale it times 3. 0..1 would be **Red** to **Yellow**, 1..2 would be **Yellow** to **Green** and 2..3 would be **Green** to **Blue**. You can reuse this function to create a transition for each block.

I haven't written everything down, but maybe this is a step in the right direction.

For (pseudo) example:  **(there is NO range checking, you should implement it)**

```
// specify some colors.
var colors = new[] {Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue};

// get the color corresponding to 0.5 of all colors.
GetRainbowColor(0.5, colors);


public Color GetRainbowColor(double value, Color[] colors)
{
    // calculate the count of transitions between colors.
    var colorRange = colors.Length - 1; 

    // scale the value in order of the transition count.
    var newValue = value * colorRange;

    // truncate the value to get the starting index.
    var startIndex = (int)newValue;

    // the residual value to get the transition point between the two colors.
    var residualValue = newValue - startIndex;

    // reuse a modified version of the old HeatMapColor function.
    return LerpColor(residualValue, colors[startIndex], colors[startIndex+1]);
}


public Color LerpColor(double value, Color startColor, Color endColor)
{
    // reuse some code from the HeatMapColor

}
```

---

After a discussion i wrote an example:

https://github.com/jvanlangen/WinformsRainbow/

If the link fails, here's a copy of what I've posted on github:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Gradient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DrawRainbow();
        }

        private void DrawRainbow()
        {
            // specify some colors.
            var colors = new[] { Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, Color.Blue };


            var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

            // draw the rainbow
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                // for each verticalline
                for (var x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
                {
                    // transform x (0..width) to 0..1
                    var value = x / (double)bitmap.Width;

                    // get the color corresponding to 0.5 of all colors.
                    var color = GetRainbowColor(value, colors);

                    // draw vertical line
                    using (var pen = new Pen(color))
                        g.DrawLine(pen, x, 0, x, bitmap.Height);
                }
            }

            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        }

        public Color GetRainbowColor(double value, Color[] colors)
        {
            // calculate the count of transitions between colors.
            var colorRange = colors.Length - 1;

            // scale the value in order of the transition count.
            var newValue = value * colorRange;

            // truncate the value to get the starting index.
            var startIndex = (int)newValue;

            // the residual value to get the transition point between the two colors.
            var residualValue = newValue - startIndex;

            // reuse a modified version of the old HeatMapColor function.
            return LerpColor(residualValue, colors[startIndex], colors[startIndex + 1]);
        }


        public Color LerpColor(double value, Color startColor, Color endColor)
        {
            // reuse some code from the HeatMapColor

            int r = (int)((endColor.R * value) + (startColor.R * (1 - value)));
            int g = (int)((endColor.G * value) + (startColor.G * (1 - value)));
            int b = (int)((endColor.B * value) + (startColor.B * (1 - value)));

            return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawRainbow();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: great approach! But to me it's unclear where I can pass my max and min value. For example, I have a 100 as my value and my upper bound is 200 and my lower bound is 0. 0 should be red, 200 should be blue ...

Comment: @SimonGiesen I would not combine a min and max in that function. Just create a small function that converts 100 (where min = 0, max = 200) to 0.5   yours  `double val = (value - min) / (max - min);`

Comment: ok. Thank you! I got an "Index out of bounds" error: return LerpColor(residualValue, colors[startIndex], colors[startIndex]); at startIndex, it's getting values below 0 and above 3 ... any tips?

Comment: See the: **(there is NO range checking, you should implement it)**  so when you pass a value below 0 or above 1, you need to clamp them  (if value<0 value = 0)

Comment: ok, did it. I use in LerpColors

try
                {
                     

                    int r = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(255 * val));
                    int g = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(255 * (1 - val)));
                    int b = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(255 * (2 - val)));

                    return Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
                }
                catch (OverflowException)
                {
                    return Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
                }
But I get values beyound 255

Comment: for rainbow colors it seems not to work, with range checking enabled I get only a map with two colors and values between

Comment: _h.Floor(255 * (2 - val))); ret_ this doesn't look right... the LerpColor gets a value between 0..1 for each color[start], color[end]. The trick is that the input value (0..1) is converted to 0..3. The non-decimal value is used for the index and the residual is used to check the value between the colors.

Comment: int r = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(startColor.R * val));
                    int g = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(startColor.G * (1 - val)));
                    int b = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(startColor.B * (2 - val)));

doesn't work either. not seeing the forest for the trees :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248920/discussion-between-jeroen-van-langen-and-simon-giesen).